# Accessing extra column in many-to-many relationship with simplified association objects

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to work with the example in the [SQLAlchemy docs: Simplifying Association Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects)

What I am struggling with understanding is how I can access the special_key. Ultimately I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
for user in users
    for keyword in user.keywords
        keyword.special_key
```

Here is the code from the example:

```
class User(Base):
__tablename__ = 'user'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(64))

# association proxy of "user_keywords" collection
# to "keyword" attribute
keywords = association_proxy('user_keywords', 'keyword')

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

class UserKeyword(Base):
__tablename__ = 'user_keyword'
user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
keyword_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('keyword.id'), primary_key=True)
special_key = Column(String(50))

# bidirectional attribute/collection of "user"/"user_keywords"
user = relationship(User,
            backref=backref("user_keywords",
                            cascade="all, delete-orphan")
        )

# reference to the "Keyword" object
keyword = relationship("Keyword")

def __init__(self, keyword=None, user=None, special_key=None):
    self.user = user
    self.keyword = keyword
    self.special_key = special_key

class Keyword(Base):
__tablename__ = 'keyword'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
keyword = Column('keyword', String(64))

def __init__(self, keyword):
    self.keyword = keyword

def __repr__(self):
    return 'Keyword(%s)' % repr(self.keyword)
```

Am I on the right track in following this pattern here?

My goal is essentially many-to-many with an extra column containing a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for user in users:
    for keyword in user.user_keywords:
        print keyword.special_key
```